# HTML table CSS colour only for text, not for border?

Tags: css

I have tried the following, but it makes the border also red. I want to make only text red. Is that possible?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    .class2,
    .class2 tr,
    .class2 td {
      border: solid 2px;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    
    .class1{
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table class="class2">
    <tr class="class1">
      <td>hello</td>
      <td>world</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>hello</td>
      <td>world</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you do not set a color to borders, it uses currentcolor, which is the color set on the element, so td inside class1 will have borders and text red.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus So, if I do not want to specify a colour like `black` to `border-color`, but use the default value (i.e., `black` would not work well, if the user is using dark mode and the background is black and the text is white) for the border colour, what should I do? I have tried `border-color: inherit` or `border-color: unset` but they did not work.

Comment: unset(and others of the kind) will not work since it is inheritable, what you can try to  do, is to use CSS var() to set light and dark mode .  See this page, it will give hints how to manage this https://css-tricks.com/dark-modes-with-css/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a rule into the class to override the border-color:

```
.class1 td {
  color: red;
  border-color: #000;
}
```

However, I would normally add the color to the main border declaration like so:

```
.class2,
.class2 tr,
.class2 td {
  border: solid 2px #000;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to specify a tag with the color class for the text, like this with the span element and it should only color the text while keeping borders in the original color.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    .class2,
    .class2 tr,
    .class2 td {
      border: solid 2px;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    
    .class1{
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table class="class2">
    <tr>
       <td><span class="class1">hello</span></td>
       <td><span class="class1">world</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>hello</td>
      <td>world</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove td from .class1 td , that td is causing to apply the style on table too , and the color tag works just on text if nothing else is specified

Comment: Removing td still makes the border red.

Answer (score 0):

Having read your comments since my original posting, it maybe worth you having a look at media queries, as it seems you can target user themes using them (although this may currently have limited browser support).  For me, running dark theme on my machine, I see a yellow border, but in light theme, I see red.  (For reference I'm using Google Chrome).  This way, you can set a border color for both light and dark themes.

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    .class2,
    .class2 tr,
    .class2 td {
      border: solid 2px currentcolor;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    
    .class1 td {
      color: red;
      
    }
    
    @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
      .class1 td {
        border-color: #FF0;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table class="class2">
    <tr class="class1">
      <td>hello</td>
      <td>world</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>hello</td>
      <td>world</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the border-color rule to your table to set the border color as black.

```html
    .class2,
    .class2 tr,
    .class2 td {
      border: solid 2px;
      border-collapse: collapse;

      border-color: #000;

    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).